# Scan for new wireless networks continuously in adhoc mode

Tags: wireless, network-monitoring, adhoc

I have two laptops in an ad-hoc mode (with same essid, broadcast id, etc.). Sometimes, they don't ping each other even though they are next to each other.

I always have to initiate a scan from each of those using `sudo iwlist`, then again try to ping from one computer to another to see if the connection between them works.

I want my laptop to continuously scan for new wireless networks in a area (as one more laptop might enter this network). I'm not sure if this (scanning) occurs continuously or not.

I'm running:

```
$sudo iwlist wlan0 scan
```

every few seconds to do this. I know I can write a shell script to do this continuously.

I was wondering if there was a easier way of making my wireless card continuously scan for changes in list of wireless networks.

Answer (score 0):

Personally i like solutions with GUI, so here is one:

[LinSSID - Graphical wireless scanning for Linux](http://sourceforge.net/projects/linssid/)